# Arrays with variables in their titles (Bash)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Here is my situation:

- Use the `bash` interpreter (NOT ZFS or dash or anything else) that ships with macOS (3.2.57 as of macOS Ventura)
- The variable `platform` can be `1`,`2`,`3` or `4`
- I have four arrays called `array1` to `array4`, all containing IP addresses. These have been set up using `array1=(1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3)` but I can set them up in any way the script needs them
- I need to set a final variable, `finalPlatform`, which uses the number from the `platform` variable to obtain the arrays from the relevant `array` variable and map the values across, such that querying `finalPlatform` when `platform` is equal to `4` is the same as querying `array4`
- I then need to be able to add items to this `finalPlatform` array after the fact

Here's what I have right now, which doesn't work:

```
#set these variables artificially for the sake of testing
platform=2
array2=(1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 4.4.4.4)
#declare 'finalPlatform' as the contents of the variable 'arrayX' & then verify
declare "finalPlatform=array$platform"
echo ${!finalPlatform}
```

This will produce the first value in the array but there's no way to even pass the conditional `[1]` (or `[@]`) to check if the other values past the zeroth have been set, much less use them.
This produces the exact same result:

```
eval "echo \$array${platform[*]}"
```

I suspect I am missing something simple but I am at the end of my tether so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: bash array indices starts from `0` so you could try, `echo "${array2[platform-1]}"`, or use an Associative array.

Comment: @Jetchisel There's no `$array` variable, there are four variables `$array1` through `$array4`. They're trying to access the array dynamically.

Comment: Ok, my bad for comprehension reading failed :-(

Comment: @seagull, `ZFS` is a file system not a shell, you're probably referring to `zsh` ...

Comment: Yeah, good shout. I'll edit the question, but only once I'm certain it's not a dupe of the one it's been closed in favour of.